# Trying to create a new react native project

Tags: linux, permissions, expo, linux-mint, permission-denied

I want to create a new react native project. At first, I faced a problem when I ran `npm install -g expo-cli` and I solved it by installing nvm, then installing node and npm by nvm. When I ran `expo init NewProject`, I got this error. 
Could you help me solving it, please?

```
  Uncaught Error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 
'/home/pgf/.expo/state.json.1309825572'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/pgf/.expo/state.json.1309825572'
}
```

I tried `sudo expo init`; I got this `✖ Something when wrong installing JavaScript dependencies. Check your npm logs. Continuing to initialize the app.` and it created a project. Bur when I ran the project with `expo start` I got this error

```
Uncaught Error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/pgf/.expo/state.json.2684774492'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/pgf/.expo/state.json.2684774492'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pgf/.npm/_logs/2020-05-29T19_37_07_602Z-debug.log
```

and this error when I ran it with `sudo expo start`

```
Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Please install it with `yarn add expo` and try again.
```

Could you help me solving this?

Comment: Have you tried running it with "sudo"? for example "sudo expo init"

Comment: Yes, I added what I got in the post. @ElliottWeeks

Comment: That error suggests your node modules don’t exist try - npm install -- save or expo install . Then retry running expo start. Make sure you are in the project directory :) good luck

Answer (score 3):

For me, there was no need to run it with sudo, since I ran into permissions errors. I had to reinstall expo-cli globally without using sudo. After that in your project directory:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.expo
npm run start
```

Comment: Saved me a few hours :D Thanks!